# JPA/Hibernate @Entity Annotation not being processed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a JPA/Hibernate MVC application that connects to two different Oracle schemas and uses JSF on Tomcat to display/manipulate data. The Entity classes for the data are annotated with @Entity and it all works fine. Let's call this project "A"

I have a second application (let's call it "B") which uses the same Model from project A so I have an ant build in B which builds the Model classes from A into a jar file and this is referenced by project B. (Just for info project B will be deployed to a separate server and only accessed via REST calls so it does not need the View elements of project A).

Most of the Entity classes called from Project B work fine, they are recognised as entities and get populated with data, etc. However with one Entity class I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity". If I exercise the same Entity class from within Project A it works fine, so it is not a configuration issue with the class or persistence.xml.

I have been investigating this for a few days and have tried various things, including pulling the Entity classes out into a third "Core" project that is referenced from the other two, A and B, this made matters a lot worse because none of the @Entity classes then seemed to be recognised as entities. This led me to think that the part of JPA/Hibernate that does whatever it does with the annotations to make an @Entity annotation into a useable entity class is not running on some classes and so they end up not being recognised as entity classes and so I see the "Not an entity" exception.

So, could my hunch be correct that the annotations are not being processed for some reason? And if so how do I fix it?

If not, what am I missing?

edited to add: I am not using Spring (or Maven due to security restrictions)

Comment: How are you loading your @Entity classes? There are different mechanisms ranging from manually listing them in the JPA persistence.xml config file to using spring and classpath scanning to auto-detect.

Comment: What's the default? because AFAIK I have not configured anything to load them, just added the @Entity annotation. For the class that doesn't work I have added <class>...</class> to the <persistence-unit> in  persistence.xml but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

OK, so following the response from @Ben Thurley I went to double check and noticed that I had added the explicit reference to the class in persistence.xml to the wrong persistence unit. So adding

```
<persistence-unit>
    <class>package.and.classname</class>
```

does fix the problem but I would still like to know why I have do it explicitly for one class and not for 21 others?